# Twenty twelve responsive menu - open downwards

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I make the responsive menu in Twenty Twelve theme open downwards?
When the window is too small to show every menu items, the menu compresses to a button MENU. If you click on it, you can see the menu items, but they open upwards.
How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the menu links are already appearing below the button, at least on the [Wordpress live demo](http://twentytwelvedemo.wordpress.com/). If that's not doing anything for you, you can try some jQuery magic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('#menu-main-menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```